# Windows Froms DialogBox Size is Changed for an unknown reason

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a class library that is a replacement for the .Net MessageBox.

When I test it with a simple forms application (Just the form containing one button), it works fine regardless of where is invoke it from, the main program, the Form.Load Event, or the Button.Click event.

When I test it in an app that has a much more complicated form (TableLayoutPanel, DataGridView, and a couple of Threads running) and invoke my MessageBox class, the Dialog form has been truncated (not shrunk) in both dimensions.

When I debug that app and look at the size of the dialog form before the ShowDialog, the sizes and location of all component in the MessageBox are as they should be.

I'm looking for thoughts on what might cause this to happen. How can one Form influence the display of a second Form.  As far as I can tell the MessageBox class doesn't reference the main form in any direct way that I can see.

It's been a long time since I've worked on a Windows Forms app and I am sure I am missing something basic.

Regards,
Jim

Regards,
Jim

Comment: Can you please show some code that determines and sets the dimensions of the `DialogBox`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to post the code so I am posting pictures of the purpose built message box class when invoked from a simple form (Form and Button) and from a more complex form.
In both cases the call to the "message box class:" is identical and both apps are invoking the same class:

[[image: Simple Form:[1]]

[image: Complex Form]

Answer (score -1):

Nearly impossible to tell you a real answer without seeing what you've coded.

However, check the AutoScaleMode propoerty of the forms in question. The complex form may be set to use DPI scaling which would cause things like fonts and position to scale and a fixed pixel-sized form would then appear to be "truncated"